Is it Possible to Successfully Do a PhD in the UK Without Formal University Enrolment?
I was previously a PhD student for 2 years, about 15 years ago, but I had to drop out due to financial problems. I had 3 related peer-reviewed publications during that time, but the subject area has moved on and I probably would need to start from scratch. The subject area is (was )machine learning with applications in health and medicine.
I still have financial problems, but I am now semi-retired (I'm 59 years old) so I have plenty of time - I just don't have the financial resources to pay for tuition fees. I have maintained good contacts at the university I was registered with, one of whom is my former primary supervisor. I am going to approach him about this but I wanted to get my facts straight as much as possible first. Hence my post here.
Is it possible to pursue and successfully complete a PhD in the UK without formal enrolment at a university. Specifically, are there any alternative pathways for independent researchers to conduct PhD-level research and eventually obtain a doctoral degree without being a registered student?
I would appreciate any insights or examples of non-traditional routes, as well as any associated challenges or considerations.
I have looked through seemingly related answers, but they don't really address my own situation:
Can I get PhD without enrolling into full-time program in UK
Is it possible to submit a paper to a scholarly, peer-reviewed journal without a PhD and get it accepted?
PhD without Enrolling in Formal Program
Can I get a PhD if I did research without being enrolled in a PhD program?

Is it the degree you are after, for example to open up a certain career path, or is it mainly the research experience? The latter you could get without the degree if your former advisor agrees to work with you, don't you think? That is, if you do not expect to be paid...

And to add to @Snijderfrey's comment: if it's the degree itself you're after, that's a formal outcome of a degree program at a university.

This is possible in the German university system, as I wrote in an answer here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/212662/private-sector-professional-being-screened-out-of-phd-program/212683#212683

It is worth noting that some universities offer part time PhD positions, which can lower the annual fee burden.

under certain circumstances it appears to be possible. Of course, you may need to spend 36 years in one of the greatest rock bands of all time first: http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/entertainment/6961171.stm

In Brian May's case, the subject area had not moved on, and he completed his astrophysics degree by just continuing his original research. In the OP's case, it's a brand new degree and would require, I expect, being a normally registered PhD student.

@DavidA.Craven - given it was less than a year between returning and finishing his thesis, I suspect he was well on his way with the writing already. One year to remember stuff from 30 years ago, do some literature search to see what was new, and finishing up seems actually quite fast.

It would certainly be possible to be given an honorary doctorate, but you have to come pretty close to winning one of the Nobel prizes for a good school to award that, or donate a heck of a lot of money to a lesser school. And people do distinguish between those two cases.

I don't know about the UK, but in the USA I know at least one case where a university violated a number of written rules to award a PhD to a student who had withdrawn many years earlier but published a number of papers in the interim.  It was a case where the work good enough that he ended up with postdoc offers at top places in his area.  The only reason he actually needed the degree was that the postdocs required it because of the bureaucracy of funding agencies, but really the degree was a formality.

There might be exceptions to this at some UK university, but I believe the standard answer is no. The UK system doesn't really work like that, and universities wouldn't gain much but risk a slippery slope by making exceptions.
There is a decent amount of funding available for doing PhDs in Computer Science, in particular in machine learning. You might be able to even get a stipend as well as get your fees covered. Asking your former supervisor about that seems more fruitful.
Another route could be that some universities waive the PhD student fees for staff members. You might be able to get staff status by taking a part-time teaching position (if you have relevant industry experience you'd have quite a bit to offer here), and thereby be able to enroll as a PhD student for free.

Thank you (+1)! I did do quite a lot of teaching while I was a PhD student back then, so that is definitely something to explore. From what I have heard it's extremely difficult to get funding in my situation. When I said I maintained connections at the university, that's a bit of an understatement. My former supervisor and I have become quite good friends. Our families are getting together this afternoon for example so I will certainly bring this up with him now that I've got some feedback here. Thanks again :)  Just a small point - you said "..in particular in CS" - did you mean ML ?

@Lynchian Indeed, CS was meant to be ML.

In short, it would be difficult, if not impossible to complete a PhD without some sort of enrolment in a university, mainly because to be given a doctorate it must be awarded by a university. Usually a supervisor must oversee the PhD, and upon completing it, a board must meet to decide whether to award the doctorate or not, while one answers various questions on the topic.
However, there are certainly various ways that one could obtain a PhD without having the money to pay for tuition fees.
1. Some universities pay you to do a PhD
Some universities advertise various PhD positions, which include a stipend to live off, as well as one's tuition fees paid for in full or in part. The advantages of this are obvious — it's financially sound. The only disadvantages really are that it is competitive, and you are usually restricted on the topic (many universities will advertise what specific abstract they want the PhD to be focused on).  Most people go for this route.
2.  Scholarships and bursaries
There are many scholarships and bursaries for PhD students, which can either fully or partially pay one's tuition fees, and often include some sort of maintenance loan. Be proactive with looking for these. Sometimes they may be attached to a university (upon a Google search, it seems the University of Sheffield and Imperial College offer scholarships attached to the institution, as well as Oxford and Cambridge which offer so many scholarships that it would be difficult to list them here). There are charities which provide funding, and councils such as the Research Council.
If you have good links to academics from a past university, it is definitely worth emailing them to show that you are interested in a PhD. They may be able to tell you more on specific funding there, or they may have useful connections.
Here are a few links which may help you:

https://www.findaphd.com/
https://www.jobs.ac.uk/search/phds
https://www.postgraduatestudentships.co.uk/funding-opportunities
https://www.imperial.ac.uk/jobs/career-programmes/phd-vacancies/
https://www.ox.ac.uk/admissions/graduate/fees-and-funding/fees-funding-and-scholarship-search/scholarships-a-z-listing
https://www.postgraduate.study.cam.ac.uk/funding


There is the concept of Doctor of Philosophy by publication, ie you have published some volume of work in the academic literature and a PhD is awarded based on those publications, and perhaps some other kind of assessment (viva voce, public lectures, etc).  If you search for that you find various universities that offer it.  The fees are probably not zero but perhaps less than 3 years of tuition and ancillary costs (housing etc).
As to whether it is a practical approach for your specific circumstances, I don't know.  One difficulty with publishing in the ML/healthcare field is you'd need access to resources - servers, data, hospitals, ethics committees... - which might be difficult to achieve as an independent researcher.  However you might be able to collaborate with people in universities who can give you access to such things.
It sounds like you're in touch with your former supervisor who might be able to advise whether this is a sensible approach, and perhaps have contacts in places where it might be allowed.

This answer and the Wikipedia article you link conflate two different things: (1) a candidate goes through a full PhD programme, but their final “thesis” consists of several articles rather than a single monograph; (2) the candidate bypasses some or all of the usual programme, with pre-existing publications.  The first of these is very (and increasingly) widespread, but doesn’t particularly address OP’s question.  The second kind would answer OP, but I’ve never come across it outside historical examples — if you’ve really found universities offering this, I’d be very interested to know where.

Portsmouth, Westminster, York St John, Sunderland, Cambridge were top of search 'PhD by published work'

Aberystwyth, Bristol, UEA, Staffordshire, Glasgow, ...

Reading, Kingston, Manchester, Ulster

QMU, Warwick, ... There are pages and pages of search results of universities that offer them, far too many for the comment character limit :-)
